# preg_match allow blank line or text

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to use preg_match on a from to be able to allow either blank or text

regex I have is

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/
```

I have tried many different ways adding \s or \0 in different places however It doesn't make a difference.

code snippet

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/",$address1)) {
    $error = true;
    $s1name_error = "Street Address can only contain letters, numbers and spaces";
}
```

I am trying not to get all these error to show when on of the above preg_matches get caught.

[image]

Comment: `^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$` only matches 1 or more ASCII letters or digits or regular spaces, isn't that what you need?

Comment: Yes however if the line is blank it will still show the error.

Comment: `^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$)|(?:\s*$)` Try this

Comment: Maybe you want to be able to match any whitespace and allow empty string? `/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*$/`?

Comment: @bassxzero  Yours allow special charcters

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yours worked perfectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want to allow any whitespaces and an empty string input, too.

Use `\s` instead of a space, and replace the `+` with `*` quantifier:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q5xjo3/1).